# How do I set a style but exclude classes and their children?

Tags: html, css, less

I have less which is styling a div on my page. I'd like to create some less to exclude divs with a particular class, along with all their children.

Here's my (simplified) html:

```
<div class='people'>
    <div>
        <!--This text should be green-->
        Bob
    </div>
    <div>
        <!--This text should be green-->
        Geoff
    </div>
    <div class="ex-members">
        <div>
            <!--This text should remain red--> 
            Mary
        </div>
        <div>
            <!--This text should remain red--> 
            Fred
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the less I'm trying to use:

```
body {
   color:red;
}
.people {
   &:not(.ex-members) {
      color:green;
   }
}
```

But this seems to just set all the names to green.

N.B. I could of course solve this by overwriting the green color and setting ex-members back to black again, but I'd like to avoid doing this if possible.

Comment: `&:not(.ex-members){` note the dot and remove quotes

Comment: @Morpheus Thanks, that was a typo. Still seems to behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a direct descendant selector `>`

```
.people {
   > :not(.ex-members){
      color:green;
   }
}
```

which compiles to...

```css
body {
  color: red;
}

.people> :not(.ex-members) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='people'>
  <div>
    <!--This text should be green-->
    Bob
  </div>
  <div>
    <!--This text should be green-->
    Geoff
  </div>
  <div class="ex-members">
    <div>
      <!--This text should remain red-->
      Mary
    </div>
    <div>
      <!--This text should remain red-->
      Fred
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ex-members` div is inside your `people` div, and your second style is looking for elements with a `people` class and no `ex-members` class on them. The simple solution is to just remove the `&:not`.

```
.ex-members {
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: The ex-members are the ones that are supposed to be red.

Comment: Then put `color: green` on `.people` and `color: red` on `.ex-members`. It's much easier to understand than using `:not` to do the same thing.